# Unable to parse bindings. knockout error

Tags: knockout.js

this is my day 2 learning Knockout.

Trying to attach "deleteItem" for button click. it gives the following error.

> Error
>
> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: deleteItem is not defined; Bindings value: click: deleteItem

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var defaultData = [{
        id: 1,
        item: "Todo 1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        item: "Todo 2"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        item: "Todo 3"
    }];
    var viewModel = {
        listItem: ko.observableArray(defaultData),
        addItem: function () {
            // Add new item
            var id = this.listItem().length + 1;
            this.listItem.push({
                id: id,
                item: "Todo " + id
            });
        },
        deleteItem: function () {
            alert(this);
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, main);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">+ Add Item</button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: listItem">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: item" />
        <input type="button" data-bind="click: deleteItem" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

The function `deleteItem` is on your view model.  When you're binding inside the `foreach`, the context of the binding operation is the individual `item` from the `listItem` array.  You need to bind to `$root.deleteItem` to reference the root view model.

Comment: I recommend using `$parent.deleteItem`, so that you only step up a single level. `$root` may not always be accurate.

Comment: @srieen -- Great!  Please see Tyrsius's comment too.  Context is important.  Also, don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted answer.